# jQuery Mobile: Submitted form not staying on "thank you" page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery mobile, I have just started using it for a WordPress site that's supposed to be only used via a smartphone. I like the way it looks now that I added jQm to the equation.

The problem I have is that after I submit a form, it correctly takes me to the "thank you" page, which at this point is just a single line of text reading "thank you for playing", but immediately after that it goes back to the original form where it came from. I might not be able to explain this better, so I recorded a video with the issue here: http://screencast.com/t/QMD0BProSg

If I disable ajax with "$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;" it works, meaning it doesn't go back to my form, but having ajax enabled and working the way it's supposed to, will get rid of a couple of other issues I have. Fixing this behaviour will save me a lot of time!

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="stop-spin" action="/thanks-for-playing" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="stop-spin-nonce" name="stop-spin-nonce" value="c96ef6a79f">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/spinner/">
</form>
<div class="play-button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="start-rotation" class="ui-link"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="stop-rotation" style="display: none;" class="ui-link"></a>
</div>
```

I removed the extra elements for the sake of simplicity, but it's worth noting that my form doesn't have a button inside, what I do is capture the Click event of the #stop-rotation anchor via jQuery and I do the form submit there.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$( document ).on( 'pageinit ready', function() {
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.play-button a#stop-rotation', function() {
        $( '#stop-spin' ).submit();
    });
});
```

I might be missing something obvious here, can anyone help me out with this?

At the moment this little app is local only, but I can try and build a fiddle or upload to my test server if anyone wants to take a look at it as a whole.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: add return false; after   $( '#stop-spin' ).submit(); and see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your code, this should do the job. You'll never need the ready() event in JQM, replace it with pageinit() or pageshow() for example.

```
$( document ).on( 'pageinit', function() {
    $( '.play-button a#stop-rotation' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $( '#stop-spin' ).submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does the same :s any other idea?

Comment: Probably this might help, I just noticed when the thing goes back to the original page I get this error: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on page prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'bindRemove'. It happens if I click the Spin button a second time

Comment: thanks tronc, it actually worked on the live server, so I won't worry about this anymore